# Blazor / How to insert SVG tag value from the model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, svg, blazor

I want to use inline svg dynamically.
I don't want to use  or  tags or create classes.

The problem is - I don't know how to call string variable (or property) from inside of  tag. Is there any attribute which may take text from the model properties?

In other words - how to use dynamic SVG in the Razor component?

```cs
@foreach(item in Collection)
    {
        <svg someAttribute = @item.Icon > </svg>
    }

@code {
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Icon {get; set;}
    }   
        
    public List<Foo> Collection { get; set; } =
        new List<Foo>
        {
                new Foo { Id = "Navigation", Icon = "svg value bla bla bla"},
                new Foo { Id = "Navigation", Icon = "
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-house" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 13.5V7h1v6.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V7h1v6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 2 13.5zm11-11V6l-2-2V2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5z"/>
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.293 1.5a1 1 0 0 1 1.414 0l6.647 6.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 2.207 1.354 8.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L7.293 1.5z"/>
                "}
        };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to dynamically add a block of static HTML content, you can wrap the HTML content in a `MarkupString` value.

```
<svg>@((MarkupString)item.HtmlContent)</svg>
```

For more information, please check this doc about "Rendering raw HTML": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#raw-html